# How to sort list by number of characters in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, if I have a list:

```
list=['00100','100','0100']
```

I want the output to be:

```
list=['100','0100','00100']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
l = ['00100', '100', '0100']
sorted(l, key=len)
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the length of strings at all.. it's completely different from what the OP is after.

Comment: @JonClements Sorry, I misread the question. I've changed my answer.